# Apache PDFBox zoom is not working in browser

Tags: java, zooming, pdfbox

Using Apache PDFBox 2.0.6, I am trying to zoom-in that PDF page using following code...

```
public File zoom(int pageNumber) {
    try(PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(getInputFile())) {
        PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
        PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNumber);
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDPageXYZDestination destination = new PDPageXYZDestination();
        destination.setPage(page);
        destination.setZoom(1.5f);
        destination.setLeft(200);
        destination.setTop(200);
        action.setDestination(destination);
        catalog.setActions(null);
        catalog.setOpenAction(action);
        document.save(getOutputFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getOutputFile();
}
```

Yes it is working code, until you don't open this PDF in any browser. In Adobe PDF Reader, I can see zoom, but on browser, unable to see zoom. It is like **Fit To Page** always if I am opening the same PDF in any Browser like Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge.

Please help me to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Browser based PDF viewers often are limited and don't support the full standard. Probably this zooming simply is not supported...

Comment: You should create an issue in PDF.js. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/ Before creating the issue, try with https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html . And don't forget to attach your PDF in the issue.